# Google tool that suggests website improvements

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I seem to remember there being a Google tool that gives feedback on your website and suggests improvements with regards to how it is built and how mobile-friendly it is etc.

Is there such a thing or might I be getting mixed up with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's hosted web page performance testing tool:

https://web.dev/

Google's Chrome browser's built-in web page performance testing tool:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse